# How can I get the DOS path name of a running process in C# / Win32?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop

**To sum it up, I need to do this:**

> 12345(hWnd) -> "C:\setup.exe"

---

Right now, I am using [`GetProcessImageFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the Kernel Device Path of a process handle.  I'm retrieving the handle using [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx), passing it the PID.  The PID (which I also need) is being retrieved using [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx).

However, this gets me to a string like:

> \Device\Harddisk1\setup.exe

At this point, I enumerate all drives on the system using [`DriveInfo.GetDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx), and then call [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365461%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Finally, I can do some string-manipulation magic, and "**boom**," I have my path.

---

Ok, so my issues:

1. **This process breaks down on Network drives.**
2. All I really want is [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919%28VS.85%29.aspx) on XP

There HAS to be a better way to do this.  Please enlighten me, oh gods of WIN32API!

Comment: Have you/your process which make enumeration administrative rights?

Comment: However, I'm just retrieving the drive name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious question would be why you don't just use `QueryFullProcessImageName`, if that's what you want? Do you need compatibility with older versions of Windows?

The closest equivalent to `QueryFullProcessImageName` that's available on XP is probably `GetModuleFileNameEx`. I'd probably detect whether `QueryFullProcessImageName` is available and use it if possible, otherwise fall back to `GetModuleFileNameEx`.

Edit: While `GetModuleFileNameEx` isn't 100% dependable at retrieving the name of the executable for every possible process, it does work at least a fairly substantial part of the time. Here's a quick bit of test code I put together:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

std::string getfilename(DWORD pid) { 
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
    static int winver;
    char path[256]= {0};
    DWORD size = sizeof(path);

    if (winver==0) 
        winver = GetVersion() & 0xf; 

#if WINVER >= 0x600
    if (winver >= 6)    
        QueryFullProcessImageName(process, 0, path, &size);
    else
#endif
    if (!GetModuleFileNameEx(process, NULL, path, sizeof(path)))
        strcpy(path, "Unknown");
    return std::string(path);
}

typedef std::map<DWORD, std::string> win_map;

namespace std { 
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, win_map::value_type const &v) { 
        return os << v.first << ": " << v.second;
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK show_info(HWND window, LPARAM lParam) {
    win_map &exes = *(win_map *)lParam;

    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, &pid);
    exes[pid] = getfilename(pid);
    return true;
}

int main() {
    win_map exes;
    EnumWindows(show_info, (LPARAM)&exes);
    std::copy(exes.begin(), exes.end(), std::ostream_iterator<win_map::value_type>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

The results of a quick test are somewhat interesting. Compiled as 32-bit code, the version using `QueryFullProcessImageName` found 33 processes with top-level windows, and found names for 31 of those executables. The version using `GetModuleFileNameEx`, also found 33 processes, but only found names for 21 of the executable. If, however, I compile it as 64-bit code, *either* version finds filenames for 31 out of 33 executables (and the same two fail). Given the frequency with which you see XP/x64, that's probably of little consequence, but I found it interesting nonetheless.

In any case, even the least capable version (32-bit/GMFNE) found names for ~2/3<sup>rds</sup> of the files. While that's certainly not what you'd hope for, it's certainly better than nothing.

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName doesn't work on XP.  Yes, I need this to work on older OSes.  I am planning on using the Vista+ api if it is supported.

Comment: Oh, and `GetModuleFileNameEx` doesn't work for a module across in another process.

Comment: Works as well!
Now the current GetVersion() is deprecated.maybe we should looking for an alternative function.

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond: [`IsWindowsVistaOrGreater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424965.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It must be possible to retrieve the file path to running processes since Sysinternals' Process Explorer does it.  Of course, Process Explorer uses [NtQueryInformationProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28VS.85%29.aspx), which isn't a supported function. (On the other hand, since you're specifically targeting XP and would use `QueryFullProcessImageName` on Vista and later, the fear of the API becoming unavailable in a future version of Windows is probably not a concern.)

[CodeProject has an article about how to use `NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/GetNtProcessInfo.aspx).